# Django - compare user objects by field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a Dictionary view that shows the list of words created by a specific (special) user:

```
class Dictionary(FilterView):
    model = Word
    template_name = 'vocab/dictionary.html'
    context_object_name = 'dict_list'
    paginate_by = 15
    filterset_class = WordFilter
    strict = False

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user')
        return qs

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = qs
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        if pk is None:
            raise AttributeError('pk expected in url')
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
```

Now I want any user to be able to come to this page and add any word that they want to, like this:

```
def custom_create_word(request, object):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass
    if request.method =="GET":
        from .forms import WordForm
        from .models import Word
        word = Word.objects.get(pk=object)
        user = request.user
        target_word = word.target_word
        source_word = word.source_word
        deck_name = "My Words"
        fluency = 0
        new_word, created = Word.objects.get_or_create(user=user, target_word=target_word,
                                     source_word=source_word, deck_name=deck_name, fluency=fluency)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('vocab:dict'))
```

Everything works as expected. But **in the template I want the button to look different depending on whether the logged in user already has this word in their own list** (which should be judged by if target_word is the same). My template looks like this:

```
<tr>
      {% for word in dict_list %}
      <td>{{word.target_word}}</td>
      <td>{{word.source_word}}</td>
      <td>
      {% if user_word %}
        <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >Added</a>
      {% else %}
          <a href="javascript:" class="add-word btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-wordpk="{{word.pk}}">Add</a>
     {% endif %}
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

**The way I thought about doing this is to overwrite `get_context_data` on my Dictionary view so that I can check if the logged in user's target_word is equal to the special user's target_word**, and to pass this into context. So my view is:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = WordFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
    special_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user', target_word='target_word')
    logged_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, target_word='target_word')
    user_word = None
    if special_user_word == logged_user_word:
        user_word = True
    context['user_word'] = user_word
    return context
```

But I get `None` everywhere... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work!

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = WordFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        special_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user').values_list('target_word', flat=True)
        logged_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values_list('target_word', flat=True)
        user_word = list(set(special_user_word) & set(logged_user_word))
        context['user_word'] = user_word
        return context
```

And in my template:

```
{% if word.target_word in user_word %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously they won't be same, because the `Word` objects are totally different as they are created differently for each user inside `custom_create_word`. Also,  `user_word` won't work for all the words, you need provide it for each word. You can override the `get_queryset` method like this(using [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)):

```
from django.db.models import Value, Case, When, BooleanField

class WordListView(...):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(**kwargs)
        special_user_word = Word.objects.filter(user__username__iexact='special_user', target_word='target_word').values('source_word', flat=True)
        return queryset.annotate(
            user_word=Case(
                When(source_word__in=special_user_word, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
                output_field=BoolenField()
           )
        )
```

Usage in template:

```
{% for word in dict_list %}
   {% if word.user_word %}
       already added
   {% else %}
       add
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I knew the way I was doing it was wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to compare the target words for the users. So this is very helpful. However, when I try to implement it I get the following TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): True.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. I have updated it.

Comment: Still not getting the desired result in my template... are you sure I should use `word.user_word'?

Comment: yes, I have annotated that attribute with each word. But you need to verify if the logic is correct or not. I am checking for source word. Is it right or should be something else?

Comment: No, it should be target_word, but that's not the error, I already changed that. I'll try again.

Comment: I tried everything, but it's still not working. Could you please take another look?